# Why does calling expand-file-name indirectly produce a different result?

Tags: files, dynamic-scoping

Running the following in ielm in `emacs -Q`:

```
ELISP> (defun wh/expand-file-name (name &optional default-directory)
  (expand-file-name name default-directory))
wh/expand-file-name
ELISP> (expand-file-name "http://example.com" nil)
"/home/wilfred/http:/example.com"
ELISP> (wh/expand-file-name "http://example.com" nil)
#("/scp:http:/example.com" 1 4
  (tramp-default t))
```

Why do these two functions not return the same value?

Comment: I suspect it may relate to `file-name-handler-alist`, but I'm mystified as to how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short: dynamic binding.

It is maybe a little unfortunate that `default-directory` was used as the argument to `expand-file-name`.

Note the docstring:

> (expand-file-name NAME &optional DEFAULT-DIRECTORY)
>
> Convert filename NAME to absolute, and canonicalize it.
>   Second arg DEFAULT-DIRECTORY is directory to start with if NAME is relative
>   (does not start with slash or tilde); both the directory name and
>   a directory’s file name are accepted.  **If DEFAULT-DIRECTORY is nil or
>   missing, the current buffer’s value of ‘default-directory’ is used.**

By dynamically binding a `nil` value for `default-directory` around the call to `expand-file-name`, that becomes *both* the argument passed by your function *and* the fall-back value which is used "If DEFAULT-DIRECTORY is nil or missing". That is the difference between the two variants, as normally the fall-back value would be a string.

n.b. <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `default-directory`

You would get the same result with:

```el
(let ((default-directory nil))
  (expand-file-name "http://example.com" nil))
```

If you change the name of that argument in your function, this will stop happening. e.g.:

```el
(defun wh/expand-file-name (name &optional defaultdir)
  (expand-file-name name defaultdir))
```

Note that `expand-file-name` *itself* is written in C and is not subject to this same behaviour, which is why it gets away with using that name as an argument, but you do not.

Comment: Bingo! and Bravo!